# “.htaccess” and “.htpasswd" files for each webpage

Tags: html, .htaccess

I have an index page which has links to 3 pages (all in the same directory):
file1.html, file2.html, file3.html.

```
<html>
<body>
<ul>
    <li><a href="file1.htm">file1</a></li>
    <li><a href="file2.htm">file2</a></li>
    <li><a href="file3.htm">file3</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I am new to “.htaccess” and “.htpasswd", all the tutorials I have read allow access for 1 to many users to a page. In my case I want the opposite. I want 1 “.htaccess” file and 1 “.htpasswd" file that would do the following:

allow username:Bob pass:123 to access only file1

allow username:Nick pass:123 to access only file2

allow username:Randy pass:123 to access only file3

nobody else can access the 3 pages.

does anybody know how can I do that?

Since all the 3 pages are in the same directly I cannot just create 3 “.htaccess” for each page, which is making me so confused. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to simply move the three files to three different directories. So you'd have:

```
<li><a href="file1/index.html">file1</a></li>
<li><a href="file2/index.html">file2</a></li>
<li><a href="file3/index.html">file3</a></li>
```

Then you can easily create a separate `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd` in each of those three directories.

Having said that, it is possible to use a single `.htaccess` file to apply restrictions to more than one file.

```
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
AuthName "Example"
AuthType Basic

<Files "page1.html">
  require user bob
</Files>
<Files "page2.html">
  require user nick
</Files>
<Files "page3.html">
  require user randy
</Files>
```

Note that you still have a single `.htpasswd` file with credentials for Bob, Nick, and Randy. (Even with three separate directories you'd still want one `.htpasswd` so you're not chasing credentials all over the place.) But then those `<Files>` blocks allow only certain users to access the three various files.